# Windows Ce Mobile. Motorola MC550 out of memory exception

Tags: c#, memory, windows-ce, motorola

I have written 2 applications in .net for windows ce devices using vs 2008 and compact runtime 3.5. I tested it on several machines and the emulators that came with vs 2008. We installed it at a customer site and started getting 'out of memory exception' errors at random times. The customers were using MC55 scanner devices which had mobile 6.0 operating systems. The machines had PLENTY of memory and mobile 6.0 allows each app up to 2GB. The apps do download a large amount of data and had 16-20 mb of memory usage. The error usually happened at random points when the app was retrieving data from the server but also threw the error sometimes when allocating memory. The errors always caused the device to lose network connectivity.
Does anyone know if these devices are faulty or perhaps have a corrupted version of dot net installed? It smells like a memory leak somewhere in the code that performs webservice functionality.

Comment: How much physical memory do these devices have? CE 6.0 does support 2GB of virtual address space per application, but that is of little use if they run out of physical memory to back the data.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two things I would check first.

1. Have you dispose all the Disposable objects before they go out of scope?
2. If you have got event subscription for long running objects/instances have you unsubscribe when you finished using them?

Comment: The objects in memory are simple models (property bags) and do not need or posses any dispose methods to be called on them. The data I am downloading are byte streams. I am not using any event handling on any data objects, just my UI controls (a few winform usercontrols). The programs run without incident on many other machines.